# Better way to download files directly using Amazon S3 API - SDK on ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon provides a vast documentation, but there are so many docs that I'm lost, so here is my current service for upload/download files. Upload works as expected but on the download its where I have to download the files to a physical path and later serve the download to the user, I don't have much experience working with streams. Here is the FileManagerService class that connects to Amazon API.

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
public class FileManagerService
    {
        public FileManagerService()
        {
            string serverPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
            string uploadPath = Path.Combine(serverPath, "FileUploads");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
            UploadDirectory = uploadPath;
        }
        private string UploadDirectory { get; set; }

        private docucloudEntities db = new docucloudEntities();

        private IAmazonS3 S3Client = new AmazonS3Client();

        private string S3Bucket = "bucketname";

        public async Task<string> DownloadFile(string AmazonFileKey, string FileName)
        {
            var fileRequest = new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = S3Bucket,
                Key = AmazonFileKey
            };

            var localRoute = Path.Combine(UploadDirectory, FileName);

            using (var fileObject = await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(fileRequest))
            {
                if (fileObject.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    fileObject.WriteResponseStreamToFile(localRoute);
                }
            }
            return localRoute;
        }
    }
```

This method returns the string, it's not complete yet with try catch blocks, but it currently works. Here is my controller method that download the file to the client:

```
public class FileManagerController : Controller
{
    private FileManagerService FileService = new FileManagerService();

    public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadFileAmazon(long FileId)
    {
        if (db.Archivos.Any(i => i.ArchivoID == FileId))
        {
            var archivo = db.Archivos.Single(i => i.ArchivoID == FileId);
            var rutaarchivo = await FileService.DownloadFile(archivo.Ruta, archivo.Nombre);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(rutaarchivo))
            {
                var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(rutaarchivo);
                var response = new FileContentResult(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream");
                response.FileDownloadName = archivo.Nombre;
                System.IO.File.Delete(rutaarchivo);
                return response;
            }else
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
        }else
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

So here on the controller I read the file bytes and serve the download, after deleting the file, but this could lead to a slower perfomance, its there a way of achieving direct download.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no reason to dispose `GetObjectResponse` (return type of `GetObjectAsync`) even if the docs says so. `GetObjectResponse` is not implementing `IDisposable` but is inheriting `StreamResponse` that is. However, as far as I can tell [it's only disposing the `ResponseStream`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/Model/StreamResponse.cs#L33-L69). So you could return the stream from `GetObjectResponse` (`fileObject.ResponseStream`) together with the `ContentType`from the headers (`fileObject.Headers.ContentType`) that you then can return as a file in your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("blob/{filename}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        var file = await _fileStorageService.GetBlobAsync(filename);

        return File(file.Stream, file.ContentType);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
    }
}
```

`FileResult` will dispose the stream after it has written the file so there the stream will finally get disposed.